# GDAL CreateCopy is very slow

Tags: gdal

I am processing some 4096x4096 JPEG2000 images with OpenCV and my resulting image is missing all the GDAL metadata.  I have implemented a copy method in my C++ program to use GDAL CreateCopy to copy the meta data from the original image to the destination.  So far I am seeing a copy time over 97 seconds on a basic metadata copy.  This is longer than all my image processing put together!  I have tried increasing the GDAL cache to 200, and even to 10485760.  Setting it at either value makes the time even worse!

Comment: How did you arrive at 10485760, since GDAL_CACHEMAX is given in MB?

Comment: @Kersten I guess I wasn't 100% sure it was actually MB, because some of the docs mention Bytes.  10485760 is 10MB.